# How to VNC into Ubuntu 10.04 from a Mac

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, ubuntu-10.04, vnc

I'm trying to remote login into my Ubuntu machine from my Mac following the instructions at this website:

[link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/)

When I try to login, I confirm to allow access on the Linus side, but on my Mac, it just says "Contacting 192.168.1.65" and doesn't do anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VNC into an Ubuntu machine from a Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/76559/vnc-into-an-ubuntu-machine-from-a-mac)

Comment: I saw that before and it didn't solve the problem so I posted this.

Comment: please give us details of what you tried, what worked, what didn't, from this question, so we can help you better.